# App with TextChangedListener crashes when text field is empty

Tags: android

I'm trying to display an equation result in an EditText.

It works fine until I clear the value from the text field, which is when the application closes

```
mDrq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.drq); 
mEDitTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01); 

mDrq.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Ltrs=mDrq.getText().toString();
                Double LTR=Double.parseDouble(Ltrs);

                if(Integer.parseInt(Ltrs)>10){

                    Double drq=((0.20)*(LTR));
                    mEDitTxt.setText(""+drq+"");
                }

            }


         });
```

Comment: When something like this happens you should look at Logcat as the errors tell you what is wrong (and if you cant solve it, post the Logcat on your question)

Comment: logcast display [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: " " ,java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248),java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295) ]

Comment: just what i expected, the answer i already posted should fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Likely your issue is

```
Double LTR=Double.parseDouble(Ltrs);
```

throws a `NumberFormatException` because Ltrs (which should be lowercase btw - uppercase is for classes) will not be parsable to a double.

Fix it like this:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    String text = mDrq.getText().toString();
    try {
        Double dbl = Double.parseDouble(text);
        if (Integer.parseInt(txt) > 10) {
             Double drq = ((0.20)*(dbl));
             mEDitTxt.setText(String.valueOf(drq));
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldnt parse textfield", nfe);
    }

}
```

Please take note of the other fixes like `String.valueOf` too